# Significant difference/ANOVA test when some values occure only once

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, python, small-sample

I have fake dataframe with neighbrhood codes and prices of houses in those neighbrhoods, with this amount of values for each negihborhood:

```
df['neighb'].value_count()

>>>
a    17
b    5
c    3
d    2
e    2
f    1
g    1
f    1
```

**I need to check if there is significant difference in the prices between the neighbrhoods.** The problem is that some neighbrhoods have price of only one house, so I don't have group of values as I only have data regard this one house specifically.

**Assuming that I cannot get more data regard house prices,** (in this task)

Is there any way I can calcualte **if there is significant difference in the prices between the different groups?** I wanted to use ANOVA but as the groups are really little I find it problematic (also regard the assumption of normal distribution etc).

*clarification : my real database is not prices of houses, is somethiing that I cannot get more data then what I want but I do need to check if there is significant differences between different neighbrhoods when some have alamost no observations.

Comment: If you have only one price for some groups, I wonder whether you you can do an ANOVA that includes these groups. In your data, maybe you can combine (f,g,h) into a group called 'other'.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following simulated data. Notice that standard deviations
differ by group, so I use the `oneway.test` procedure, which uses a
Saterthwaite approximation to give a reasonable P-value.

```
set.seed(2021)
a = rnorm(17, 1000, 10)
b = rnorm( 5, 800,  10)
c = rnorm( 3, 2000, 15)
d = rnorm( 2,  500,  8)
e = rnorm( 2, 1100, 10)
fgh = rnorm( 3, 800, 20)
x = c(a,b,c,d,e,fgh)
g = rep(1:6, c(17,5,3,2,2,3))
```

This one-way ANOVA procedure works fine, and finds a highly significant
difference among groups in my simulated data.

```
oneway.test(x ~ g)

    One-way analysis of means 
    (not assuming equal variances)

data:  x and g
F = 2317.8, num df = 5.0000, denom df = 5.1515, p-value = 1.298e-08
```

Using the Bonferroni method to protect against 'false discovery' in *ad hoc*
tests on these data, you might reject two-sample Welch t tests only
for P-values below 1%.

It is not surprising to find a sigificant difference *ad hoc* between
`a` and `b` because of the difference in sample means and 'reasonable'
sample sizes of 17 and 5.

```
t.test(a,b)$p.val
[1] 5.717784e-09
```

But some pairs of groups with very small sample sizes are also significantly
different. For example,

```
t.test(c,e)$p.val
[1] 0.0001867002
```

Of course, I cannot say what will happen with your real data, but at least
we know that `oneway.test` with *ad hoc* comparisons using Welch t tests
is not automatically doomed to failure. I would say that comparisons of
the group `fgh` of 'leftovers' might be difficult to interpret, but you
really don't have meaningful data there.

Comment: thank you for your answer. so if I understood you correct, you reccoment to use the one-way ANOVA test even if I cannot check the assumptions, and use the Bonferroni method in order to make sure I select the best a value? and also , you were assuming that groups with one observations  can create new group together? (im working with python so i'm appologize if I did not understood some things you did)